# How to set mininet server resource like core?

Tags: linux, load-balancing, sdn, mininet, ryu

Anyone here is know how to set the server resource like core in mininet? I've using express.js to run server on mininet, but i want to simulate the weighted round robin load balancing method, but i don't know how to set the server resource.

Comment: Do you want to run the load balancing with the switches in Mininet (and/or the controller) or distributed by another HTTP server?

Comment: I want to run the load balancing with mininet switches that connected to controller